# Apache Ignite: Select query performance

Tags: ignite, singlestore

We have inserted a table in Ignite with 10 million rows. 
The execution time for the following query is around 10 seconds:
**select * from tableName offset 5000000 rows fetch next 100 rows only**
The Ignite database was installed on servers with 150 GB RAM.

The same table was inserted in MemSQL database on same hardware environment and the above query was executed in 6 seconds.

Why is the execution time so long in Ignite database?
Is there something missing in Ignite while executing select queries with
huge offset?

Please let me know if you require any further information regarding our test case.

Regards,
Shravya.

Comment: That seems like an odd query -- without an order by clause there's no real guarantee of _which_ 100 rows you're going to get each time. What are you trying to achieve? With a normal query, I'd ask about how many nodes you have and your table structure (indexes, affinity keys).

Comment: Even if there was something odd, 6s and 10s are the same order of magnitude so the question about "something missing" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First, please make sure that you are not running out of memory by allocating enough memory to the JVM. Second, please add "order by" and an index on the field you are sorting. This should improve the performance.

Comment: Creating index helps but our users normally select 4-5 columns of a table and then sort and search. Some of the tables we migrated from older RDMS have about 200+ columns and it is obviously not practical to create index on different combinations of columns. In general, we found that memsql was using some sort of smarter caching technique to do sorting and its performance was better than ignite.